# RecyclerView onClickListener Setup Performance

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick, onclicklistener

so i tried to implement `onClickListener` for my RecyclerView for the first time and I've been wondering if what i did is actually worth doing. In my application i have different Recycler Views, and i don't need both `onClickListeners` and `onLongClickListeners` at the same time in most of them, so I wanted to do it so that i don't have to implement them both in my `.setOnItemClickListener`. I basically check which `onClickListener` is set up with enum mode, and then according to that i set my listeners in `onCreateViewHolder`. Does it even makes sense to do that? Or should i just implement both listeners and don't do what i did in my code?

```
public class FreindRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FreindRecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ClickListener clickListener ;
    private LongClickListener longClickListener;

    private Context context;
    private List<String> friends;
    private ListenerMode mode;

    public enum ListenerMode {NullMode, ShortClick, LongClick}

    public interface ClickListener {

        void onItemClick(int position, View v);

    }

    public interface LongClickListener {

        void onItemLongClick(int position, View v);

    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        mode = ListenerMode.ShortClick;
    }

    public void setOnLongItemClickListener(LongClickListener longItemClickListener) {
        this.longClickListener = longItemClickListener;
        mode = ListenerMode.LongClick;
    }

    public FreindRecyclerViewAdapter (Context context, List<String> friends) {

        this.context = context;
        this.friends = friends;
        this.mode = ListenerMode.NullMode;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view;
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.friend_item, viewGroup, false);
        final MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

        if(mode == ListenerMode.ShortClick) {
            myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    clickListener.onItemClick(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), view);
                }
            });
        } else if (mode == ListenerMode.LongClick) {

            myViewHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                    longClickListener.onItemLongClick(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), view);

                    return true;
                }
            });

        }



        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int position) {

        myViewHolder.friendName.setText(friends.get(position));


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return friends.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView friendName;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            friendName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.friendName_ID);

        }

    }

}
```

**EDIT**: Now that i think of it, i don't even know why it does work, like when i set up my RecyclerView, adapter and all in my code below, I first tell the adapter about the list I want to show on the screen in it's constructor `recyclerViewAdapter = new FreindRecyclerViewAdapter(this, friends);`, so this is when `onCreateViewHolder` is called for my views. So now when everything is created (ViewHolders) I call the function to set up the OnClickListener, which in my code adds different listeners according to the `mode` that is set up, and those listeners are added in `onCreateViewHolder`, which was already called, so why does RecyclerViewAdapter (and how does it know to) call the `onCreateViewHolder` again to add the listeners?

```
friends = new ArrayList<>();

        friends.add("Josh");
        friends.add("Mike");
        friends.add("Ashley");
        friends.add("Jess");


        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewFriend_ID);
        recyclerViewAdapter = new FreindRecyclerViewAdapter(this, friends);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

        DividerItemDecoration itemDecor = new DividerItemDecoration(this, linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecor);



        recyclerViewAdapter.setOnLongItemClickListener(new FreindRecyclerViewAdapter.LongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(int position, View v) {
                Toast.makeText(FriendActivity.this, "Long Click. Position:" + Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's ok but it can be better.

**1) You are creating a click listener and long click listener for every position**

You don't need to create a listener for every position like you are doing here:

```
myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() ...

and

myViewHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() ...
```

Since they are performing the very similar action, you can create only one click and longclick listener and share with all views. To make that, move the `itemView.setOnClickListener()` and the `itemView.setOnLongClickListener()` to the `ViewHolder` class.

You need to save the position in the ViewHolder as well. So, they will be able to store their own position.

**2) You don't need to create a enum**

You don't need to create a enum to check if current mode (click or long click). Instead, you can just check if the variables are null, for example.

In the end, you can have a code like this:

```
public class FreindRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FreindRecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ClickListener clickListener ;
    private LongClickListener longClickListener;

    private Context context;
    private List<String> friends;

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }

    public interface LongClickListener {
        void onItemLongClick(int position, View v);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public void setOnLongItemClickListener(LongClickListener longItemClickListener) {
        this.longClickListener = longItemClickListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view;
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.friend_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view, i, clickListener, longClickListener);;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int position) {
        myViewHolder.friendName.setText(friends.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return friends.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
            View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnClickListener {

        private TextView friendName;
        private int position;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView, int position) {
            super(itemView);
            friendName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.friendName_ID);
            this.position = position;
            if (clickListener != null) {
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
            if (longClickListener != null) {
                itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onItemClick(position, view);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            if (longClickListener != null) {
                longClickListener.onItemLongClick(position, view);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Note that now, each view holder knows its own position
- View holder implements the regular `View.OnClickListener` and `View.LongClickListener`. So, you don't need to instantiate a new listener for every position.
- If you want to enable the click, call `FreindRecyclerViewAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(object);`
- If you want to enable the long click, call `FreindRecyclerViewAdapter.setOnLongItemClickListener(object);`
- If you want to disable any of them, don't call the methods above or just call them passing `null` as parameter. If you check the code in `MyViewHolder`, you can see that any action is performed when those listeners are null

Hope I could help and share more ways to achieve what you want!!!

Comment: Isn't the `i` variable in `return new MyViewHolder(view, i)` actually not the position, according to the google documentation `i` in `onCreateViewHolder` is the ViewType, only in `onBindViewHolder` `i` is the position, which I renamed in my code. And i'm a little bit confused about not creating many onClickListeners, you said that implementing `onClickListener` to the `ViewHolder ` avoids creating multiple listeners, but doesn't this line `return new MyViewHolder(view, i)` creates new ViewHolder for each view which basically creates new onClickListener (itself) with it?